# problem of using bibitem in harvard style

Tags: harvard-style, bibitem

i am willing to publish a paper in a journal that require the HARVARD reference style
i uploaded the .bib file but the output didn t comprise the references list
so i have been told to use the bibitem to enter the references manually, however i get an error ; bibliography not compatible with author year citation (natbib)
any help
thank you in advance

here are all the packages i used for the article

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,nccmath}

\usepackage{commath}

\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{slashbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\usepackage{cuted}

\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{moreverb,url}

\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,citecolor=red,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).